# Is it possible to get database tables/functions called by an Spring Restful API

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, logging, java-8, log4j2

I am building a debugging tool to analyze the database calls made by each endpoint.

Is it possible to list the database (tables/functions) calls made by an endpoint (Spring Restful API) and display to the UI built for debug tool for developer environment? I am using Spring Boot, Hibernate, Java 8, Oracle12c database.

I am not sure which feature of spring framework to use this. I am working on already existing application and I tried using actuator but if I use it then no other endpoint seems to be working in my application.

I tried setting org.hibernate.SQL to true which logs all the queries and its difficult to reach very big log files for each request made and display the queries. I cannot change the logger level dynamically so unable to achieve it.
Is there any other approach?

Any help appreciated! Thanks in Advance.